# How connect Postgresql database with sqlalchemy python

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm currently writing an program using Flask python. But I can not connect my database with my program. I'm use Postgresql for database.

```
import os

from sqlalchemy import create_engine

from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URI"))

db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
```

This is the code what I'm using for it, But it didn't work. So please help me to connect my database

This is the error message that what I have got,
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZomj.png)

Comment: What seems to be the problem? Please include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Showing the error message would be a good start.

Answer (score 2):

Configure database string

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@hostname/database_name')
```

Connect db then:

```
import psycopg2
conn_string = "host='localhost' dbname='my_database' user='postgres' password='secret'"
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

**db.py** File which contains db connection(postgres url)

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost/DB_NAME'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

**app.py** This is your main file database tables will create when your server hits the first request.

```
from db import *
@app.before_first_request
def before():
    db.create_all()

enter code here......
```

**table_structure.py** This file contains your table structure

```
from db import db
class UserProjects(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(140), nullable=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

step1:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
```

step2: use following command

```py
db=create_engine("postgresql://username:passwd@localhost:port/database_name")
```

It will connect to the postgresql

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30147607)